Combining tables with different column numbers
I’ve been combining sheets out of a folder using power query. Problem I have is some sheets have 4 columns and some 3.
The first two columns in a couple of sheets are duplicates are I’m to only consider the second column in this case as it holds the correct data.
I tried deleting the first column but this also deletes for the ones with the correct format.
I’ve tried amending it from the sample file but not sure the best approach in this case. Any help appreciated, be gentle pls I’m new to all this.
Additional context below:
Expected table format:
[name] [address] [type]
Problematic table format:
[name] [name] [address] [type]
some have 4 columns, some have 3, I’m wanting to delete the first column on the tables with 4 without affecting the ones with 3 columns when combining them
Output (2)
let
Source = Folder Files("source"),
#"Filtered Hidden Files1" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <› true),
#"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Hidden Files1",
"Transform File", each #"Transform File" ([Content])),
#"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns (#"Invoke Custom Function1", {"Name", "Source Name"}),
#"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns (#"Renamed
Columns1", {"Source.Name", "Transform File"}),
#"Expanded Table Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Transform File", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transform File"(#"
in
#"Expanded Table Column1"


If the answer from @horseyride is not useful, please edit your question to provide a data sample as text which can be copy pasted that clearly illustrates your problem, and a screenshot of the results you'd expect from that data.

In Powerquery, assuming you have column data containing tables, and for each table you'd like to check if Column2 is a duplicate of Column1, then you can apply a transform step which deletes if duplicate, and then renames if appropriate
Transform = Table.TransformColumns(#"YourPriorStepNameHere",{{"data", each 
    let a=_,
    Delete=if Table.Column(a,Table.ColumnNames(a){0})=Table.Column(a,Table.ColumnNames(a){1}) then Table.RemoveColumns(a,Table.ColumnNames(a){0}) else a,
    Rename= if Table.ColumnCount(a) = Table.ColumnCount(Delete) then Delete else Table.RenameColumns(Delete,List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(Delete),List.RemoveLastN(Table.ColumnNames(a),1)}))
in Rename}})


